# Jquery.tabs: How do i use it with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to use Jquerys.tabs control. I dont see the logic. If i use PartialViews i migth as well wave goodbye to my Controller/Action logic, but then i would have to make ascx files, and i can't call those from my Controllers, or can i?

Im not nessesarily interesseted in the ajax/unload onclick part, that Jquery.tabs() offers. I just want to use it as my Menu. So when i click a menu tab it works like when i do <% Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home");. How is this possbile?

Generally i some guidance on this subject. The articles i have found on google, have'nt been to much help, unfortunaly.

I hope you can come with some great words about this.

/Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article and download example very helpful when first using jquery tabs in MVC .Net http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/jquery-ui-tabs-and-aspnet-mvc/